# Strange image display artifacts using ArUco Markers with OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 3.4 and Python 3.6 and attempting to read ArUco marker. I'm having success but I'm seeing an unexpected issue and am hoping that someone can steer me in the right direction.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import cv2.aruco as aruco

test_dict = aruco.getPredefinedDictionary(aruco.DICT_6X6_50)

img = cv2.imread(test.jpg)

corners, ids, rejects = aruco.detectMarkers(img, test_dict)

markerImg = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, corners)
rejectImg = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, rejects)

stackedImage = np.hstack((markerImage, rejectImage))

cv2.imshow("Accepts and Rejects", stackedImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The strangeness is that the stacked images are identical. Both rejects and detects are the same. If I comment out the line performing the draw of the rejects I see only the detected markers, and vice versa.

Anyone have any ideas as to what is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to determine the cause of the issue I was encountering. The function:

```
markerImage = aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(img, corners)
```

was setting markerImage and img to be the exact same object such that

```
markerImage is img
```

returned as True.

To avoid this problem I coped img using:

```
markerImage = img.copy()
aruco.drawDetectedMarkers(markerImage, corners)
```

This functionality is significantly different from most of my experience so hopefully it will help someone in the future.